# solving an equation $f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I wonder if the equation:$$2\sqrt x-\ln(x)=0$$
has any solutions. I plotted the function and it has no roots. Is there an algebraic method to show this?

Comment: On $(0,1)$ use that $\ln(x) < 0$ to see it immediately and on $(1,\infty)$ you can use asymptotic arguments ($\ln$ grows slower, so the function is increasing). At $1$ there obviously is no root either.

Comment: right...suppose one doesn't notice ln(x) grows slower; is there another way? :D

Comment: The derivative is $\frac1{\sqrt x} - \frac1x$. One can easily see that this is positive for $x > 1$.

Answer (score 6):

Setting $f(x)=2\sqrt x-\ln x$ gives you
$$f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt x-1}{x}.$$
So $f'(x)=0\iff x=1$. Note that $f(x)$ is decreasing for $0\lt x\lt 1$ and $f(x)$ is increasing for $x\gt 1$. Hence, we have $f(x)\ge f(1)=2\gt 0$.

So, there is no real solution for $f(x)=0$.

Comment: it's too plain :P

Answer (score 6):

Using the power series for $e^t$, if $t$ is positive then
$$e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\cdots>\frac{t^2}{2}\ .$$
So if $x>0$ we have
$$e^{2\sqrt x}>2x>x\quad\Rightarrow\quad 2\sqrt x>\ln x\quad\Rightarrow\quad
  2\sqrt x-\ln x>0\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

The equation can be written as:
$$x=\exp(2\sqrt{x})$$
using the $LambertW$ function you get:
$$x=LambertW(-1)^2$$
and finally:
$x=-1.687-0.8508i$ which obviously isn't real.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
It's clear that any real solution of $\ds{2\root{x} - \ln\pars{x} = 0}$ must satisfy $\ds{x > 1}$.

> Lets assume that $\ds{x = t^{2}}$, with $\ds{t > 1}$, is a solution.

$\ds{\color{#c00000}{\mbox{We'll show that it leads to a contradiction}}}$:
\begin{align}
0&=2\root{x} - \ln\pars{x}\quad\imp\quad t=\ln\pars{t}\leq t - 1\quad\imp\quad
\color{#c00000}{0 \leq -1} 
\end{align}